# Python: Insertion Sort

Tags: python, beginner, insertion-sort

I am a beginner in python and to learn python I have written this program. How can this code be improved? Should I use `main` method in this program? Python

```
lst = []

def insertion_sort(thelist):
    for index in range(1, len(thelist)):
        key = thelist[index]
        position = index - 1
        while position >= 0 and thelist[position] > key:
            thelist[position + 1] = thelist[position]
            position = position - 1
        thelist[position + 1] = key

n = int(input("Enter number of elements: "))
for i in range(0, n):
    ele = int(input())
    lst.append(ele)

insertion_sort(lst)
print(*lst, sep = ", ")
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a much simpler method in Python to do an insertion sort using the 
`bisect.insort` method

```
import bisect
array = [1,3,5,7]
bisect.insort_left(array, 2)

>>[1, 2, 3, 5, 7]
```

With regard to your coding style, I would recommend using the `if __name__ == "__main__"` guard.

You can also just say `for i in range(n)` with no need to say `(0, n)`

You can also use list-comprehension to build the list:

```
import bisect
def insertion_sort(thelist):
    new_list = []
    for item in thelist:
        bisect.insort_left(new_list, item)
    return new_list


if __name__ == "__main__":
    n = int(input("Enter number of elements: "))
    lst = [input("Please enter a number: ") for i in range(n)]
    new_list = insertion_sort(lst)
    print(*new_list, sep = ", ")
```

Answer (score 1):

- Try to make functions for every logical thing you do like getting the elements. use `def get_input()`
- Use `if __name__ == "__main__" guard`. It is a good practice when you are importing this program to another program, it will not run the code in this program entirely.
- There is no need to use a `for loop` for getting the `list` you can use `split()` on the entire input which would create a list as desired. It is pythonic to use `split()`.
- There is no need to make `n` as lists in python are dynamic. You can get the length in `O(1)` time using `len(lst)`.
- Name your variables clearly, slightly longer names are not a problem. `lst` would be `input_list` etc.
- You can use `enumerate` in `for index in range(1, len(thelist)):`. Which would give the `index` and elements of the list. More pythonic.