# Python: Selection sort

Tags: python, beginner, algorithm, python-3.x, sorting

After implementing suggestions from an earlier, related question ([Python: Insertion Sort](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/222914/python-insertion-sort)), I have written this code. Could you help me to improve this code?

```
def get_input():
    input_str = input("Enter elements to be sorted: ")
    lst = list(map(int, input_str.split()))
    return lst

def selection_sort(thelist):
    for i in range(len(thelist)-1):
        min_idx = i

        for j in range(i+1, len(thelist)):
            if thelist[j] < thelist[min_idx]:
                 min_idx = j

        thelist[i], thelist[min_idx] = thelist[min_idx], thelist[i]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    input_list = get_input()
    selection_sort(input_list)
    print(*input_list, sep = ", ")
```

Comment: It looks like a correct implementation of the sorting algorithm, so good job.  The input prompt could be more explicit that it is expecting a sequence of integers separated by spaces.  `get_input()` could handle errors in the input (e.g. if the user enters "a, b ,c"). You could add doc strings and you could add some unit tests for `selection_sort()` (e.g., sort and empty list, a one element list, an already sorted list, etc.)

Comment: @RootTwo This looks like an answer, not a comment :)

Answer (score 3):

Regarding the code itself I think functions should usually return an output and then this should be printed. It is also worth introducing some way of alerting the user if there input causes an error. I entered
`5, -3, 0` and this raised an error because your code splits on **spaces** not commas. Additionally, you are mapping the list to `int` so entering a character by mistake breaks the code

Hence saying something like

```
def get_input():
    input_str = input("Enter elements to be sorted: ")
    try:
        lst = list(map(int, input_str.split()))
    except:
        raise TypeError ("Please enter a list of integers only, separated by a space")
    return lst

def selection_sort(thelist):
    for i in range(len(thelist)-1):
        min_idx = i

        for j in range(i+1, len(thelist)):
            if thelist[j] < thelist[min_idx]:
                 min_idx = j

        thelist[i], thelist[min_idx] = thelist[min_idx], thelist[i]
    return thelist

if __name__ == '__main__':
    input_list = get_input()
    output = selection_sort(input_list)
    print(*output, sep = ", ")
```

Comment: I don't agree on there needing to be an output. Python convention is that methods that change a list inplace (`list.sort`, `list.extend`,...) do not return a value. I think this is to prevent the assumption that you need the assignment, and the original input is untouched. Here you mutate the input, and return the value. I would choose either of the 2. Your remark on `get_input` are correct. I would however surround this with a `while True:`, print the error msg instead of raising the Exception. and give the user a new chance to give input in the correct format